# Cannot access to the redux store from a react component library

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-component

I'm trying to link a react component library (**MediaPlayer**) made by me to the redux store in the host project.
**At the moment the library is in my filesystem and it's using its own node_modules/readux library** and symlinked via `npm link.`

my library exports those:

```
// component
export { default } from './components/player/Player.component';
//ts interfaces
export * from './components/player/player.interfaces';
//redux slice with actions and reducers
export * from './components/player/Player.slice';
//redux middlewares
export * from './components/player/player.middlewares';
```

my host projects imports the library slice, actions, and reducers:

store.ts

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import { IPlayer } from 'loquis-player';
import { callStopLoquis, sendGoogleEvent } from 'loquis-player';
import { slice } from 'loquis-player';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    player: slice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: [callStopLoquis, sendGoogleEvent]
})

export interface IRootState {
  player: IPlayer;
};
```

As you can see, I try to integrate the componet slice with the app store.

Then, the component got wrapped:

```
<Provider store={store}> -> <App/> -> <Footer/> -> <Player/> -> <**MediaPlayer**/>
```

But, when I try to run it, I got this error:

> 34552 |   var dispatch = useDispatch();
> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the
> component is wrapped in a

Technically it should works, but it acts as the **MediaPlayer** stays out of the redux Provider. Why?

Answer (score -1):

Have you wrapped your app inside `Provider` with redux store (somewhere on top of you app like `App.js` or `index.js`?
The error seems to suggest you might have forgotten.

```
let root = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
   <React.StrictMode>
)
```

Comment: yes, as stated in my question

Comment: My bad for overlooking it - then perhaps the store is configured incorrect. (Might just be a simple typo/ export default vs named mix)